# Gatsby: Using GraphQL Query on Custom Post Type with Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I am using Gatsby to deliver a front end to WordPress and querying data with GraphQL.

I have a post with a Custom Post Type and a Custom Taxonomy.

However when I query on the CPT, I can get the number of the Custom Taxonomy but no don't know how to retrieve the corresponding names.

Below is my query;

```
{
    wordpressWpPortfolio {
        title
        slug
        id
        portfolio_categories
    }
}
```

And this is what is returned;

```
{
    "data": {
        "wordpressWpPortfolio": {
            "title": "Test Portfolio 1",
            "slug": "test-portfolio-1",
            "id": "5caf7182-c9f5-53d9-94da-b49cfbdc6d7f",
            "portfolio_categories": [
                5
             ]
         }
     }
}
```

However, there are no other fields I can select in the GraphQL playground.

Below is my expected result;

```
{
    "data": {
        "wordpressWpPortfolio": {
            "title": "Test Portfolio 1",
            "slug": "test-portfolio-1",
            "id": "5caf7182-c9f5-53d9-94da-b49cfbdc6d7f",
            "portfolio_categories": [
                "id":5,
                "name":"portfolio category name"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to "join" the rest end points?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix It?

Comment: Can this be amended in WP with register_graphql_connection( $config )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a custom normalizer.

There is a great example on the [`gatsby-source-wordpress`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/#example-1) page which is quite similar to what you want to achieve.

Alternatively, you may want modify your CPT REST API to return both the category *ID* and *name* of the field using the [`register_rest_api()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/) method provided you are comfortable with WordPress development.

Something like this:

```
register_rest_field(
    // Custom Post Type name
    'portfolio',
    // Name of field being added to your REST API response (portfolio_categories)
    'portfolio_categories',
    array(
        'get_callback' => function( $data ) {
            $category_terms = wp_get_post_terms(
                $data['id'],
                'portfolio_categories'
            );
            $portfolio_categories = array();
            foreach( $category_terms as $term ) {
                $portfolio_category_obj       = new StdClass();
                $portfolio_category_obj->ID   = $term->ID;
                $portfolio_category_obj->name = $term->name;
                array_push(
                    $portfolio_categories,
                    $portfolio_category_obj
                );
            }
            return $portfolio_categories;
        },
    )
);
```

This will add an extra field in your REST API to called `portfolio_categories` which returns an array so you can use the GraphQL as expected.

Remember to run [`gatsby develop`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/quick-start/#start-development-server) afterwards so as to start/restart your development server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include name in the query:

```
{
    wordpressWpPortfolio {
       title
       slug
       id
       portfolio_categories {
          id
          name
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I had tried that but only an integer comes back... "message": "Field \"portfolio_categories\" must not have a selection since type \"[Int]\" has no subfields.",

Comment: There are no resolvers this is how it comes out of Wordpress RestAPI out of the box so I need someway to amend in Wordpress CPT UI (or Function) or do something else